# How can I see diff for specific changeset?

Tags: vc

I want an analog of `git show $REV` / `hg diff -c $REV` /  `svn diff -c $REV` in Emacs when I know `$REV`.

Currently I open full history via `C-x v L` and search for specific revision and then type `d` or `l` ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vc-diff-internal` doesn't show single changeset but always diff between two revisions.

`vc-diff-build-argument-list-internal` function used by commands `vc-version-diff` and `vc-root-version-diff` will ask for revisions to compare.

`log-view-diff-common` used to view diff from log view compute previous revision by calling backend for previous revision so we can do the same:

```el
(require 'vc)
(require 'vc-hooks)

(defun my/vc-view-diff-single-rev (rev)
  "Show diff for REV."
  (interactive "sRevision: ")
  (let ((backend (vc-responsible-backend default-directory)))
    (when backend
      (let ((rev-from (vc-call-backend backend 'previous-revision nil rev)))
        (when rev-from
          (vc-diff-internal t (list backend nil) rev-from rev))))))
```

Comment: Great! I know each VCS has CLI option to show specific REV, like `git show $REV`, `hg log -p -r $REV`, `svn log -p -c $REV`. Calling `previous-revision` discloses VC weakness... BTW I looked to the same source code but stopped at necessity to call `previous-revision` ((

Answer (score 0):

Magit solution:

> `magit-show-commit` Show the commit at point. If there is no commit at point or with a **prefix argument**, *prompt for a commit*.

In VC internals I can't see direct solution for the problem. `vc-git-diff` requires fileset, I am unable to get it works:

```
(vc-git-diff (cadr (vc-deduce-fileset t)) (vc-read-revision "Rev: "))
```